# Iterating over array not moving to next object after using next operator

Tags: arrays, ruby, each

I'm currently trying to parse a phone number into a PDF form. I'm braking the phone numbers into three sections , the area code, first 3 numbers and the last 4 numbers.

```
   DICTIONARY = { 
'TELEPHONE NUMBER area code 1'=> '66563943', #Primary Phone - Area code (000)
'TELEPHONE NUMBER first 3 1'  => '66563943', #Primary Phone - (000) 000
'TELEPHONE NUMBER Last 4 1'   => '66563943', #Primary Phone - (000) 000-0000
    }
```

Above are the fields into which I have to parse the phone number.

```
  {
    "field": "66563943",
    "value": "(201) 785-9896"
  },
```

As you see from the snippet above I have to parse that phone number to put them inside the PDF form field. I get to successfully break the number into are code, first 3 and last 4.

```
  elsif phone_number?(field_data[:field])
      parse_phone_number(field_data[:value])
      @phone_number_sections.each do |section|
         fill(field, section)
         field.next!
      end
    else
```

The `field_data` come as follows:

```
[10] pry(#<PdfScrie>)> field_dataield_data
=> {:field=>"66563943", :value=>"(201) 785-9896"}
```

However, the field doesn't move while iterating.

```
1] pry(#<PdfScrie>)> field
=> "TELEPHONE NUMBER area code 2"
[2] pry(#<PdfScrie>)> section> section
=> "201"
[3] pry(#<PdfScrie>)> field>)> field
=> "TELEPHONE NUMBER area code 2"
[4] pry(#<PdfScrie>)> section> section
=> "201"
[7] pry(#<PdfScrie>)> @phone_number_sections_sections
=> ["201", "785", "9896"]
[8] pry(#<PdfScrie>)> field>)> field
=> "TELEPHONE NUMBER area code 2"
[9] pry(#<PdfScrie>)> section> section
=> "201"
[10] pry(#<PdfScrie>)> field_dataield_data
=> {:field=>"66563943", :value=>"(201) 785-9896"}
```

However when I go to the form the phone number only grabs the first element in the `@phone_number_sections` array.

```
 PHONE_NUMBER_FIELD_IDS = [
    TELEPHONE_NUMBER_1_id = "66563943"
  ].freeze
```

I used the phone ID to be able to validate if the field needs parsing:

```
 def parse_phone_number(phone_number)
    @phone_number_sections = phone_number.gsub(/\D+/, "").match(/(...)(...)(....)/).captures
  end
```

[image]
This is the method that fills the form with the data:

```
 def fill_form_with_data(field, field_data)
    if address_field?(field_data[:field])
      break_address_into_state_city_zipcode(field_data[:value], field)
    elsif phone_number?(field_data[:field])
      parse_phone_number(field_data[:value])
      @phone_number_sections.each do |section|
         fill(field, section)
         field.next!
         binding.pry
      end
    else
      fill(field, field_data[:value])
    end
```

Why is the `section` not moving to the next element in the array?

```
 def fill_out
    form_fields.each do |field|
      id = DICTIONARY[field]
      @user_submission_data
        .select {|fd| fd[:field] == id}
        .each {|field_data| fill_form_with_data(field, field_data) }
    end
  end
```

If I remove `field.next!` only the last element in the array is filled into the PDF form field since field doesn't move to the next element in `DICTIONARY` as shown in the image below.
[image]

Comment: I don't see in the PRY where are you continuing to the next iteration of `#each`.. Where are you assigning the value to `field`?

Comment: @ArupRakshit you can tell from the image of the pdf form that the PDF form fields are filled only with the first element in the `@phone_number_sections` array.

Comment: Yes I see that. But for some reason, your iteration not being completed.. To catch the bug, it will be good to see more code or something similar.. I can see it is wrong, but not able to tell why... ( Here I need help from you to help you )

Comment: @ArupRakshit I'll add more code maybe this would help. I'll edit it now

Comment: @ArupRakshit I just edit the post

Comment: What are you trying to do with `field.next!`? What is inside `form_fields`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177827/discussion-between-steven-aguilar-and-arup-rakshit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write your `fill_out` method as:

```
def fill_out
  form_fields.each do |field|
    id = DICTIONARY[field]
    @user_submission_data
      .select {|fd| fd[:field] == id}
      .each do |field_data|
        if address_field?(field_data[:field])
          break_address_into_state_city_zipcode(field_data[:value], field)
        elsif phone_number?(field_data[:field])
          parse_phone_number(field_data[:value])
          fill(field, @phone_number_sections.shift)
        else
          fill(field, field_data[:value])
        end
      end
  end
end
```

No need `fill_form_with_data` method. Your problem in the current code is that, `@phone_number_sections` array iterates till its last value for each phone field. So the fields gets the last value of `@phone_number_sections` array. But the above code will fix it IMO.